# order by timestamp a mysql result already ordered by timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

hello i m made a query in which first the of friends of uid are being fetched from database and according to that notfications are being fetched from database. the problem is suppose two friends of user a, are user b and user c , then their notifications should come after the query i made like this

> user b updated profile
>
> user c commented
>
> user b liked
>
> user c rated

these are arranged according to timestamp

but its coming arranged to timestamp seperate for each friend

like

> user b liked
>
> user b updated profile
>
> user c commented
>
> user c rated

my code

```
      $frndnoti=mysql_query("select friend_id from friend_list where uid=$id and status='1'");
while($bow=mysql_fetch_array($frndnoti))
{
$frnnid=$bow['friend_id'];

$sql3=mysql_query("select * from notification 
  where title_text='Global Notification'  
    and user_id in ($id , $frnnid)
   and owner_user_id=$frnnid 
   and is_seen=0  
   order by time_stamp DESC");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql3))
{
      and so on.....
```

can the result of $sql3 can be arranged again according to timestamp ? after its being fetched ? or any way to improve this query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a long thought and try i figured out the rite query for it , i wrtitng the query here so that it could help some one stuck later on

```
$sql3=mysql_query("select n.*,f.friend_id,f.uid,f.status from notification
n,friend_list f  where f.uid='$id' and f.status='1' and n.title_text='Global 
Notification'   and n.user_id in ('$id' , f.friend_id)  and n.owner_user_id=f.friend_id
 and n.is_seen='0'  order by n.time_stamp desc");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql3))

{
 and so on.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you are nesting queries and inserting sub-query results into an array by friend_id. Either use php to sort the return structure on timestamp or use one query to fetch all notifications:

select * from notification 
where title_text='Global Notification'
and user_id = $id or user_id in 
  (select friend_id from friend_list where uid=$id and status='1')
and owner_user_id in
  (select friend_id from friend_list where uid=$id and status='1') 
and is_seen=0
order by time_stamp DESC

Although I am not too fond of that because of the repeated nested query.

Additional questions:

- What is the purpose of user_id and owner_user_id in the query?
- How are notifications inserted into the notification table?
- What is the purpose of title_text?
- Do you set the is_seen flag after you pull notifications? Are the notifications ever needed again? Wouldbe easier to use a queue.

Answer (score -1):

Double check `time_stamp` datatype is timestamp. Rename your column `time_stamp` and try again. If this also not work, an alternative is you can sort descending the array using PHP array sort functions.

Comment: emmm i double and triple checked friend , its something with the query